# How to count working 15 days and get enddate?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to calculate actual working days of my when user checkin in hotel? I want to count working days only except Saturday and Sunday. Please check below function its count working days but in parameter I entered startdate and enddate.
I want send only startdate its automatically count 15 working days and return me enddate.
//Days count

```
public static double GetBusinessDays(DateTime startD, DateTime endD)
{
    double calcBusinessDays =
           1 + ((endD - startD).TotalDays * 5 -
           (startD.DayOfWeek - endD.DayOfWeek) * 2) / 7;

    if (endD.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) calcBusinessDays--;
    if (startD.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) calcBusinessDays--;

    return calcBusinessDays;
}
```

I want like this:

```
public static Datetime GetBusinessDays(DateTime startDate)
{
    Datetime After15WorkingDaysDate;
    return After15WorkingDaysDate;
}
```

Comment: Since 21 calendar days always contains 15 workdays, just use `var endDate = startDate.AddDays(21);`

Comment: where i enter above code please explain

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Do you want to know how to call your function with only one parameter or do you want to know how to only count up working days? Please improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two methods.

The idea is to generate each date in the range, decide whether it is a Business Day, and only then add it to the result list.

`GetBusinessDaysInRange` returns a list of the dates of the Business Days between the given start and end date. End date is exclusive, i.e. if the end date is a Business Day, it will not be part of the result.

```
// Returns a list of the dates of the Business Days between the given start and end date
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetBusinessDaysInRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, DayOfWeek[] closedOn) {

   if (endDate < startDate) {
        throw new ArgumentException("endDate must be before startDate");    
   }

    var businessDays = new List<DateTime>();
    var date = startDate;

    while (date < endDate) {
        if (!closedOn.Contains(date.DayOfWeek)) {
            businessDays.Add(date);
        }
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }

    return businessDays;
}
```

`GetFixedNumberOfBusinessDays` returns a list of the dates of the Business Days from the given start with the given number of days (the method you asked for).

```
// Returns a list of the dates of the Business Days from the given start with the given number of days
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetFixedNumberOfBusinessDays(DateTime startDate, int numberOfBusinessDays, DayOfWeek[] closedOn) {

    if (numberOfBusinessDays < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("numberOfBusinessDays must be zero or positive.");  
    }

    var businessDays = new List<DateTime>();
    var date = startDate;

    while (businessDays.Count() < numberOfBusinessDays) {
        if (!closedOn.Contains(date.DayOfWeek)) {
            businessDays.Add(date);
        }
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }

    return businessDays;
}
```

The parameter `DayOfWeek[] closedOn` was introduced because you do not want to hardcode the days of the week that are not Business Days.

The return type was changed to `IEnumerable<DateTime>` so this method is more universal. If you only want the number of days and are not interested in the actual dates, just run a `.Count()` on the result. If you want the end date, call `.Last()`.

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5rvQF5) with usage examples:

```
var closedOn = new DayOfWeek[] { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday };
var start = new DateTime(2018, 07, 23);
var numberOfDays = 10;

var businessDays = GetFixedNumberOfBusinessDays(end, numberOfDays, closedOn);

int actualNumberOfBusinessDays = businessDays.Count(); // 10    
DateTime endDate = businessDays.Last();                // Friday, August 3, 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be generic method. You can add different work day in another place.

```
public static DateTime AddWorkdays(this DateTime originalDate, int workDays)
        {
            DateTime tmpDate = originalDate;
            while (workDays > 0)
            {
                tmpDate = tmpDate.AddDays(1);
                if (tmpDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||  
                    tmpDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday )
                    workDays--;
            }
            return tmpDate;
        }
```

---

```
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddWorkdays(15);
```